# jquery reverse each function and index

Tags: jquery

So I am looping through some html element in reverse like below

```
<li class="sequence">First</li>
<li class="sequence">Second</li>
<li class="sequence">Third</li>

$($(".sequence").get().reverse()).each(function(i){
               console.log(i); // this produce 0,1,2
              console.log($(this).text()); //this produce Third, Second, First 
}
```

In regular for javascript for loop one can use `$(".sequence")[i+1].` to select something other than the current item. How does one do this in jquery each function.

Comment: The same way I suppose, you have an index, and you have an array-like collection, so just go for it.

Comment: Do you mean using the `.eq()` function, like `$('.sequence').eq(i+1)`?

Answer (score 0):

check the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lis=$(".sequence");
  lis.each(function(li){
    alert($(lis.eq(li)).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sequence">First</li>
<li class="sequence">Second</li>
<li class="sequence">Third</li>
```